# Call an external web service with CXF camel

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I want to call the webservice from camel and print the response as a log like :

```
from("cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx/ConvertTemp?Temperature=37&FromUnit=degreeCelsius&ToUnit=degreeFahrenheit)
.log("Body received is ${body}");
```

I am facing issues in passing the parameters with CXF component and i am not still clear about usage of payload and how to i am accomplish the above simple thing. Am new to CXF and using camel with webservices. Can anyone help ??

Comment: Which type of service are you calling? REST or SOAP?

Comment: @niyasc Not sure i think its REST because when i hit the URL directly from the browser http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx/ConvertTemp?Temperature=37&FromUnit=degreeCelsius&ToUnit=degreeFahrenheit it works so just want to try it from within the camel context.

Comment: Can you try hitting without mentioning `cxf` component? ie, `from("http://urlhere")`

Comment: it works when i remove the cxf: from the from (). Can you please tell me why is cxf used inside camel context and whether CXF is needed for SOAP based web services

Comment: In our projects, we use `cxf` component to expose web services and to consume rest services. For consuming rest services, we simple use `http` or `http4` component.

Comment: Thanks a ton @niyasc. Can you provide me a example of a SOAP based web service project in github or so that i can understand the CXF component better. I read about passing payloads in CXF on camel official documentation but could not get much of its use and where it is widely used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139831/discussion-between-vikram-and-niyasc).

Comment: Its a SOAP service WSDL available here http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL. Also using CXF in the from means it is a producer not a consumer. In your example you are creating the webservice not consuming it.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks. how to use CXF for web service in camel. Any examples that i can refer with ?